# Capybara: save image from loaded page (not screenshot)

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'm using ruby and Capybara gem. My point is to load a page, save an image, then do some stuff with it. Web page address is the same but image differs every time when page is reloaded actually it is a captcha.

I'm trying to save an image from that page. Screenshot saved using `save_page` is not working for me in this situation.

Below please see code I used:

```ruby
require 'capybara'
requre 'capybara/dsl'
require 'pry'

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
Capybara.app_host = "some-site"

module MyCapybara
  class Crawler
    include Capybara::DSL
  end
end

c = MyCapybara::Crawler.new
c.visit('some-url')

# [21] pry(main)> c.inspect
# => "#<MyCapybara::Crawler:0x007fc999c21d60>"

i = c.find_by_id('captcha').find('img')

# [23] pry(main)> i.inspect
# => "#<Capybara::Node::Element tag=\"img\" path=\"/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[1]/img\">"

binding.pry

puts 1
```

I need to save image "contained" in `i`. Get it via url using another tool will not work because different images have the same url every time `.../captcha.jpg`.

I can't provide the exact site and screen-shots, sorry about that.

Could someone help me with this? Or I chose the non-suitable tool for that (I mean Capybara) and better is to try Mechanize gem?

Thanks!

### Solution

Please see below the js I used to save an image:

```js
// captcha_fetcher.js

(function () {
  var form = document.getElementById("appointment_captcha_month");
  var img = form.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

  return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}())
```

and then call this via `evaluate_script`:

```ruby
image_base64_encoded = page.evaluate_script(IO.read('captcha_fetcher.js'))
```

Comment: Capybara doesn't have a built-in method for that, but you could execute javasscript to drawImage(i) into a canvas element and the use getImageData to get the pixel values from the canvas and write to an external file.  If Mechanize has a way to save the image it may be easier.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've executed js using c.page.execute_script(...), and it return to me base64 encoded image.

Comment: You might want to use evaluate_script if you're returning things -- technically execute_script is defined to return nothing, so that could change at any point in time

Comment: I copied my comment over to an answer so you can mark it off

Comment: Yes, you are right about `#evaluate_script`. Also, I faced the CORS issue, but switching to HTTPS in the url resolved that issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara doesn't have a built-in method for that, but you could execute javascript ( `page.evaluate_script` ) to drawImage(i) into a canvas element and then use getImageData to get the pixel values from the canvas and write to an external file.

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question and began putting together a javascript solution as suggested by Thomas Walpole and Igor. It seemed messy so I came up with this:

```
# Get the image source URL
image_url = find_by_id('captcha').find('img')[:src]

# Open the image in a new window
image_window = session.open_new_window
session.switch_to_window(image_window)

# Take a screenshot of the new image and print it's path
p session.save_screenshot
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this thread after so long time. I cannot test your solution, but please see the update to the post, I included the complete solution which I used then.